# what exactly happens when I compile instruction __atomic_add_fetch

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, atomic, android-x86

I have a instruction in my code calling function **__atomic_add_fetch**. When I compile this code, I am getting compilation error as below

> error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_8'

I really could not understand why it is throwing undefined reference to __atomic_fetch_add_8 when I am calling __atomic_add_fetch. Could somebody please help me understand what exactly happening while compiling this code?

**Note: I am specifically looking to understand "what is internally happening that translates __atomic_add_fetch into __atomic_fetch_add_8". Not the solution to fix compilation issue.**

Comment: I guess you need to link to libatomic by including `-latomic` in the linker/compile command

Answer (score 8):

You should be using the standardized `atomic_fetch_add`.

In any case, it looks like your `__atomic_fetch_add` with the given argument type (presumably an 8-byte integer) cannot be resolved to an assembly instruction(s) on your platform so it is getting resolved to a function call for which you'll need to link `libatomic` (`-latomic`).

Edit with details:

On gcc, `__atomic_fetch_add` appears to be the compiler built in used to implement `stdatomic.h`'s `atomic_fetch_and_explicit` (which is just a simple macro name for it). As I've noted, you should really be using the standard name `atomic_fetch_add_explicit`, not the nonportable implementation detail that `__atomic_fetch_add` is.

Regardless, the issue seems to be that gcc and clang don't implement `atomic_fetch_and_explicit` with instructions on ARM (unlike on ARM64 or x86-64) but instead they generate a call to a (global-lock-using) function from the `libatomic` library. The name of the function seems to be derived from the number of bytes in the integer you're trying to fetch_add to
(`__atomic_fetch_add_8` if you're fetch_adding to `_Atomic uin64_t`
`__atomic_fetch_add_4` if you're fetch_adding to `_Atomic uin32_t`, etc.).

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/S67g7b

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The same code is successfully compiled when I am using GNUSTL as standard library. But when I am using libc++, it is failing. Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: @Pendyala -- `__atomic_fetch_add` is not part of standard C++. The name starts with two underscores, so the name is reserved for use by the implementation. Seems like you're looking at an implementation detail. Use `atomic_fetch_add`.

Comment: @PSKocik, could you please provide some insights about what exactly is happening when __atomic_add_fetch  is compiled (particularly why it is showing undefined referenc to __atomic_fetch_add_8). Googled a lot, but could not find any information.

Comment: @Pendyala I suggest you *post the code* that is failing to compile.

Comment: @Pendyala You are using a (non-portable) compiler intrinsic.  When you do that, what happens is: whatever the compiler has been implemented to do - and that could be *anything*.  If you really want to know - go look at the gcc source.